# SaveFileDialog keeps saving files to Document directory

Tags: c#, excel, saving-data

I have a weird problem, I`m saving my data in excel file with SaveFileDialog. I set RestoreDirectory to true and InitialDirectory to Environemnt.SpecialFolder.Desktop but the program keeps saving the file in Documents every time. Doesn't matter what directory I select the file end up in Documents. Any idea?

```
 private void btnExcellExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 0))
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", RestoreDirectory = true, InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop.ToString()
        })
            {
                sfd.FileName = HelpMeClass.SearchString;
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    progressBar1.Show();
                    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar1.Value = 0;
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oops! Nothing to export!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
    }
```

BackgroundWorker DoWork:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

        excel.Visible = true;
        int index = 0;

        int process = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int process1 = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        int process2 = dataGridView3.Rows.Count;



        ws.get_Range("A1", "C1").Merge(); // Merge columns for header
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Keyword: " + HelpMeClass.SearchString;
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true; // Bold font in header

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                ws.Cells[index + 1, 1] = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        index = 0;         
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process1);

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                ws.Cells[index + 1, 2] = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        index = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process2);

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                ws.Cells[index + 1, 3] = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        ws.Columns.AutoFit();



        try
        {
            ws.SaveAs(HelpMeClass.SearchString, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ooops! I can`t access the file. Make sure the excel file is closed and try again. " + ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to include a `Path` when calling `SaveAs` so you get full control of where the file is being saved. While the parameter is called `Filename`, you can pass a full path as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-saveas-method-excel):

> A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. **You can
>   include a full path**; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in
>   the current folder.

So instead of:

```
ws.SaveAs(HelpMeClass.SearchString, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

you would call:

```
ws.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HelpMeClass.GetExcelDirectory, HelpMeClass.SearchString), XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```